# How do I make a search bar with only top left and bootom right corner?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I make a searchbar with top left and bottom right rounded corners?

The code bellow makes it all rounded but I want to be something like
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mQKT.png) in this image.
If anyone can help me I'll be very happy ^^

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/search_bar_container"
        android:background="@*android:color/primary_material_dark"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="50.0dip">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@id/search_bar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/search_bar_margin"
            app:cardCornerRadius="24.0dip"
            app:cardElevation="50.0dip"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@*android:color/primary_material_dark">

            <Toolbar
                android:id="@id/search_action_bar"
                android:theme="?android:attr/actionBarTheme"
                android:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="64dp"
                android:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_search_24dp"
                android:navigationContentDescription="@string/search_menu"                
                android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/search_bar_height"
                android:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.SearchBar"
                android:title="@string/search_menu" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a background.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:topLeftRadius="19dp"
android:topRightRadius="0dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="16dp"
/>
<solid
android:color="#002f00"
/>
<size
android:width="270dp"
android:height="60dp"
/>
<stroke
android:width="2dp"
android:color="#00fe00"
/>
</shape>
```

set background of an edit text using this drawable. Change the radius values to get your desired radius.

the output is like

[image]